# Understanding NSView/NSWindow mouse capture and dispatch

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I'm trying to understand how Cocoa's dispatch of mouse messages works while the mouse button is pressed.

My background is in Window's programming so this the perspective I'm coming from...

1. Window sends mouse down event
2. The app can call SetCapture(hWnd) to request all future mouse events get delivered to that window, rather than the window under the mouse
3. The app calls ReleaseCapture when done to restore normal mouse dispatch
4. The app might receive a WM_CANCELMODE message which instructs it to release capture and cancel any tracking modes. (eg: Windows sends this if you Alt-Tab away in during the mouse drag operation)

So learning my way around Cocoa, the way I understand it is...

1. NSWindow/NSView receives NSLeftMouseDown event
2. Cocoa automatically "captures" the mouse and sends NSLeftMouseDragged events while the mouse button is held to the window/view that was clicked.
3. NSWindow/NSView receives NSLeftMouseUp event

Here's my questions:

1. Is there a way for a window to cancel the captured mouse and explicitly re-capture it to another window?
2. Is there a way to find out which window (and/or view) currently has the mouse "captured"?
3. Are there any scenarios in which a view might receive unbalanced mouseDown/Up events?
4. Is there an event like WM_CANCELMODE that I should be watching for to cancel the current tracking operation?

To explain what I'm trying to achieve, I have a slider control in my app:

[image: Slider]

that on mouse down shows up a larger version in a popup window:

[image: SliderCap]

When it pops up the mouse cursor is automatically moved to the larger slider's handle and tracks the mouse until it's released after which the popup is removed and the cursor moved back to the smaller slider.  ([Here's a video](https://youtu.be/3kh9ivNw_qQ) showing it)

I need to either redirect captured mouse events to the popup NSWindow, or in my mouse tracking loop known which NSWindow currently has the mouse captured.  I could work this out by tracking mouse events but thought there might be an API to get it (eg: like Window's GetCapture() API).

btw: I actually have this working but what I've done feels a bit hacky and I'd like to understand OSX's approach better - and just make sure I'm not missing anything obvious/easier.

Comment: Is the slider a `NSlider` or a custom control?

Comment: It would have to be a custom control to handle the mouse event, correct?

Comment: Actually leads me to a question I never realized I had, do AppKit controls have their own implementation of `-mouseDown`?  So like if you subclassed `NSSlider`, overrode `-mouseDown`, could you accidentally remove the original functionality of the slider (moving the knob?)

Comment: Not NSSlider - a custom control.

Comment: If I were designing this, I probably would have gone with leaving the mouse pointer on the slider

Comment: @tbodt the idea behind this is to save screen real-estate with the small slider while the larger popup gives a more precise view and more finely grained control (which is important for musicians).

Comment: I don't understand which problem you're trying to solve but here's the documentation: [Handling Mouse Dragging Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW18). Controls use a cell and `trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:`.

Comment: @Willeke thanks. I'm aware of the linked document but it doesn't answer the question. Using cells isn't an option in this case (at least not an easy option especially since I have something that does work).

Comment: How does the control work and what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Willeke as mentioned in the original post I actually have this working but wanted to check if there was a better way and to understand how OSX manages this.  What I want to achieve you can see in the linked video above.  What I'm asking is this: after clicking the mouse and dragging, OSX sends the mouseDrag events to the original view that was clicked on - can I change this and get those events routed to different window/view?

Comment: @BradRobinson Do you remember how you achieved this? I'm trying to do something similar but I cannot cancel the capture from the initial window.

Comment: @Furkanzmc.  The best way I could find to implement this was to spin my own event loop during the showing of the popup and deliberately send events to the appropriate window.  See here: https://gist.github.com/toptensoftware/eccfdccf754895c502d4f2ff10d9f1e5 (it's C# but you should be able to translate fairly easily).

Comment: I was hoping to do this simply by changing the key window. But I tried to do it in a couple of way, and when NSWindow recieves a mouse down it has to be followed by a mouse up. I had a similar problem with some other project, and we were able to send a custom mouse release event to get around that. But with that, I was sending the event with Qt's event system. I'll try to see If sending it through Cocoa calls would make a difference. Thanks for the code sample. That will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:**  *I started this answer, and it ended up getting away from me.  Sorry for the long read, but I believe I covered everything about events and responders that you'll need to know, as well as some tips with issues that I've experienced over time.  Hopefully my explanations are simple and understandable, just let me know if you need more elaboration ^^*

I was going to say-- based off your video it looks like you have it working :)

So there's plenty of documentation out there that covers what I'm about to explain, but I'm going to try to share my simplified understanding of the key points, and hopefully that is more helpful than the Apple Reference

First, the rougher OS concepts that somebody will probably correct me on (not really that important to your question anyways):

- There are "run loops", which basically listen and handle events.  Each run loop is associated with a thread
- The run loop associated with the main thread is the one that receives the mouse events and keyboard events

Then, the more important concepts that I'm positive of:

- After the event is received, it is passed to the active application via the message `-sendEvent:` (Checkout the `NSEvent` category in `NSApplication`)
- The application determines the window that is key, as well as determine the corresponding message for the event (a left mouse click would get the `-mouseDown:` event)
- The window receiving the event determines the "First Responder".  Notice that any `NSView` actually inherits from `NSResponder`, and any `NSResponder` can be in the responder chain.   `NSWindow` and other AppKit objects also subclass `NSResponder` as well   [image: [1]: https://i.]
- If the event is a mouse event, it will actually send the event to the top-most view underneath the mouse
- You can override `-mouseDown:` or `-mouseDragged:` or whatever to take the event (the only parameter), and you can pass it to whatever `NSResponder` you'd like, as long as you have a reference to it of course
- If the object does not respond to the event, it will pass it down the responder chain
- The responder chain is literally just like a singly-linked list.  The head node would be the `[NSWindow firstResponder]`, and every `NSResponder` has a property called `nextResponder`

Finally, here is a screenshot of a breakpoint on a `-mouseDown:` event in one of our objects

[image]

Notice we're in the main thread, within the run loop, our application takes the event first, passes it to the window, the window determines the first responder (`CanvasMaskView`  Because this is a mouse click, this is the top-most view under the mouse), and we actually manually pass the event to the responder chain
[image]

This then enumerates over the responder chain until we finally find an object that handles the `-mouseDown:`, in `ImageController` at the top there

Last thing, notice in the call stack all the `forwardMethods`?  that is the event being passed down the `nextResponder`'s `nextResponder`'s `nextResponder` etc.

This can be proven by checking out the `$r13` register at each stack frame, which contains the current receiver of the event.  Note in this screenshot that I clicked on a stack frame, and used `po $r13` in lldb, then clicked on the next stack frame, and did the same:
[image]

This is important because you could potentially have a responder in the chain you're unaware of, that consumes the event and doesn't pass it along and you'll have no idea unless you investigate the chain.  And by "pass it along", I mean that you need to call `[super mouseDown]`, which will automatically pass the event if it needs to.

Oh yeah and final note!  If you are overriding `-mouseDown` I have found that you MUST call `super mouseDown`.  Otherwise the `-mouseUp:` event will disappear.  That's anecdotal though, I'm pretty sure `[super mouseDown]` probably registers the view with the OS so it knows where to send the `-mouseUp:`  speculation though

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, unfortunately it doesn't answer the question I'm asking.  I'm aware of the responder chain and run loops and how messages are dispatched in that regard.  What I'm not clear on is the mechanisms that are used to route mouse events to the window that was originally clicked on rather than the window the mouse is over when click/dragging.  ie:  this statement isn't always true: "If the event is a mouse event, it will actually send the event to the top-most view underneath the mouse" because during click/drag they will go to the originally clicked view.

Comment: @AO i'm also interested in this